# Return an object with multiples attributes in ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I created the object and put some attributes:

```
dynamic oReturn = new ExpandoObject();
oReturn.Name = name;
oReturn.Editing = editing;
oReturn.Img = img;
...
return oReturn;
```

But when I return the object to my front-end I have three objects, each with a key and a value instead of one object with all the attributes.

This is my output in the console:

```
m.d[0];
Object {Key: "Name", Value: "Test"}
m.d[1];
Object {Key: "Editing", Value: "177f734c-2a69-4b81-a14c-164ab9ff6704"}
m.d[2];
Object {Key: "Img", Value: ""}
```

How do I return only one object with all three attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `Newtonsoft` library, which brings the [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) class. You can then use that to serialize the object before returning it.

```
dynamic oReturn = new ExpandoObject();
oReturn.Name = name;
oReturn.Editing = editing;
oReturn.Img = img;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oReturn );
return json;
```

Note that if you are utilizing ASP.NET MVC, then you can also just return using the `Content-method` like so:

```
dynamic oReturn = new ExpandoObject();
oReturn.Name = name;
oReturn.Editing = editing;
oReturn.Img = img;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oReturn );
return Content(json, "application/json");
```

The output will then look like this once received on your front-end:

```
{"Name":"DataA","Editing":"DataB", "Img":"DataC"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dynamic oReturn = new ExpandoObject();
oReturn.Data = new ExpandoObject();
oReturn.Data.Name = name;
oReturn.Data.Editing = editing;
oReturn.Data.Img = img;
...
return oReturn;
```

than something like this should do the trick work

```
return new {Name= name, Editing = editing, Img = img};
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, but I must have expressed myself poorly, your suggestion returned an array of objects in value, I want to return an object with only three values, maybe I'd better create a class ..